# Differentiate service state

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to import a text file with service names, start the services that are in a Stopped state and then output the result to a text file. Importing and starting the services was not a problem. However, in the final text file I want to differentiate between services that had the Started state to begin with.

In the end I want a text file with a list of the services with:

- service 1   Started by script
- service 2   Started
- service 3   And so on...

My idea was to was to import the text file, check the state and output that to a new text file. Then I would change Stopped to Started by script. However, I can't always guarantee that the service starts, so this would be a quick and dirty method.

Is there a way to differentiate between these two?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Services are managed by the operating system, and those with start mode "auto" should automatically start. If they don't, there's usually a problem that you should investigate. Do not try to implement your own service management.

Comment: More of a proof-of-concept type of deal I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Get-Service` to retrieve the services from the list and add a custom property to indicate whether a service was started by the script:

```
$f = 'C:\services.txt'
$svc = Get-Content $f | Get-Service | % {
  $_ | Add-Member 'StartedByScript' $false
  $_
}
```

Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Get-Service` if you want to skip over non-existing services without an error message.

With that service list you can start services in the state `Stopped` like this:

```
$svc | ? { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' } | % {
  $_.Start 
  $_.StartedByScript = $true
}
```

The custom property `StartedByScript` indicates which service was started by the script:

```
$svc | select DisplayName, Status, StartedByScript
```